# lexicographical ordering of string list using guava

Tags: java, collections, guava

what is the simple way to do [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of string list using guava.
I do it this way:

```
List<String> s = newArrayList(
    "susen", "soumen", "dipak", "abhi", "zylo",
    "zala", "gautam", "gautom", "shaswasti", "saswati");
List<char[]> ts = newArrayList(transform(s, new Function<String, char[]>() {
    @Override
        public char[] apply(String input) {
            return input.toCharArray();
        }
    }));
Collections.sort(ts, Chars.lexicographicalComparator());
s = transform(ts, new Function<char[], String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(char[] input) {
        return String.valueOf(input);
    }
});
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: This is overkill. Just use Collections.sort in java.util package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String implements Comparable, and its natural order is the lexicographical order.
All you have to do is

```
Collections.sort(s);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want sort in place, and you would like to use guava, check out [`Ordering`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html).

```
Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(yourInputThatIsIterableAndHasStrings);
```

or:

```
Ordering.usingToString().sortedCopy(yourInputThatIsIterableThatYouWantToSortBasedOnToString);
```

If you want to sort in place, then you should just use `Collections.sort(...)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: there is also `immutableSortedCopy` to get an `ImmutableList`.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply (since `String` implements `Comparable`):

```
List<String> s = ...
Collections.sort(s);
```